# Entity Framework / SQL - Excluding multiple columns data

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I am trying to exclude some data from one of my entity framework queries but I can't seem to get it right.

```
RequestInformation.Where(x => x.RequestSubmitTime >= DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1) & x.RequestStatus != "Complete")
```

What I am trying to do is to exclude any requests that are "Complete" that are also more than a month old -- but this just excludes all requests that are complete and excludes all requests that are less than a month old.

Comment: At the very least, you will need a double && between the two.  DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1) & x.RequestStatus != "Complete") should beDateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1) && x.RequestStatus != "Complete")...  assuming this is C#.

Comment: If there's an good way to show the SQL generated rather than the framework that would be more appropriate to this forum. Probably ask entity-framework questions on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to do this:

```
 RequestInformation.Where(x => x.RequestSubmitTime < DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1) & x.RequestStatus != "Complete")
```